# I am looking for the action verb in "…he having more plenteous ideas of the same order…"

Tags: meaning, verbs, absolute-constructions

I am reading *Middlemarch* by George Eliot. I encountered this long sentence and only understood the gist of it. I can't figure out the grammar style and I am looking for the verb of the subject "he". Here is the sentence:

> Thus, the mind of Frisk was exactly of the sort for Mr. Solomon Featherstone to work upon, **he** having more plenteous ideas of the same order with a suspicion of heaven and earth which was better fed and more entirely at leisure.

Why does the sentence have "he?"

Comment: It's the typical long-winded style of 19th century novelists. I have googled the passage and find that it's actually Frick, the name of a hamlet (small village). The verb is _having_.

Answer (score 4):

The string 'he having more plenteous ideas of the same order with a suspicion of heaven and earth which was better fed and more entirely at leisure' is a lengthy *absolute construction*, not a finite clause.

A simpler parallel is

- *So, Jones was a good choice for the post, he having all the right qualifications and experience.*

Using the pronoun 'he' (etc) in such constructions is probably excessively formal and dated nowadays. A more natural sounding sentence of the same form ('with' is often added to introduce absolutes) is

- *So, the shortlist consisted of Smith and the outsider Jones, with Smith having all the right qualifications and experience.*

Comment: So “he” refers to Solomon.

Comment: @Xanne To me, it seems clear that "he" refers to Frisk. Solomon can work on the mind of Frisk due to the "more plenteous ideas" Frisk has.

Comment: @user888379 It could refer to either, but in fact Frisk (actually a typo in the OP, correctly spelled Frick) is the name of a town, not a person. So from context "he" must refer to Solomon. The "plenteous ideas" of Solomon are to be compared to the ideas of the people of Frick, described in the paragraph preceding this excerpt.

Comment: Actually a small village, as I pointed out in my earlier comment.

Comment: @Carmeister That's certainly a crucial bit of context. In my defense, it's been a long time since I read "Middlemarch".